# Joomla- 3rd Level Menu not working

Tags: joomla

https://www.sgwebdesigner.org/kimdemo/

I am getting the issue on 3rd level menu in joomla website.
Under:
AboutUs>> Our mission and vision> Testing page...( "Testing page" menu not working fine)

Any one can help please ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a css-style problem:
Remove: the width: 25% under .mb2ctm266 .mb2ctm-item-187 .mb2ctm-isparent2 in row 35

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I have removed it, but no working.
Line-1367 .mb2ctm-isparent2 {

 width: 25%;

Comment: I could not fin this file under file path...kimdemo>>media>>mb2ctmenu>>css

Comment: I got the width:25, but what about the 3rd level menu Testing page..we need it under the mission vission and value >>Testing menu..Right now the 3 menu is not fine